# How to extract the first line from a text file?

Tags: r

I have a text file that I read like this:

```
file=read.table("file.txt",skip="1",sep="")
```

The first line of this text file contains information about the file then it is followed by the observations.

I want to extract the first line and write it out to a new text file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To read the first line of a file, you can do:

```
con <- file("file.txt","r")
first_line <- readLines(con,n=1)
close(con)
```

To write it out, there are many options. Here is one:

```
cat(first_line,file="first_line.txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to read it with read.table() like this:

```
read.table(file = 'file.txt',header = F,nrows = 1)
```

This is a simple way to do it, and you can get your data separated into columns which makes it easier to work with.